# Selenium/ python performing a click with browser.execute_script VS. normal click line

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to click on something in a webpage so I used

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#styleguide-v2 > div.banner-container > a:nth-child(2)")))
```

except that it doesn't work in the background.I have to switch to the browser manually where it to be seen on my screen so that the code works properly.

Then I added this

```
x = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#styleguide-v2 > div.banner-container > a:nth-child(2)")))
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", x)
```

now it works like charm, my question is what's the difference? I want to know what's happening behind this

the webpage https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198781/
[image: The part I am clicking on]

Comment: To answer this question we first need to see the web page you are working on

Comment: In the initial code try changing `presence_of_element_located` with `visibility_of_element_located`. If it works I will explain you what is the point

Comment: Please let me know if my guess was right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`presence_of_element_located` expected condition finishes and the program continues to the next call while the element already created but still not clickable and still not located on it's final position on the page and still not ready to accept regular click.
JavaScript click can handle this kind of click, however this doesn't really imitates real UI user action.
To mimic real user action you should use `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition and click the element only when it became clickable.
`visibility_of_element_located` didn't work because the element is not actually visible itself, so we had to use `element_to_be_clickable` expected condition.
It is also possible that element is covered by some other element during the page rendering when it is literally become clickable but the page is still rendered. In this case we have to add some hardcoded delay or to wait until the element covering the desired button is disappeared. this can be achieved by `invisibility_of_element_located` expected condition for the covering element.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I believe that it is not valid in my case as I am still getting the same error TimeOutException

Comment: And if you add some additional delay after the expected condition before regular click?

Comment: I don't think it would matter as it's already given 30 seconds waiting time, however I tried adding a 5 second delay but ended up with the same error

Comment: here I'm talking not about explicit wait. Put a regular sleep there after the explicit wait..

Comment: `time.sleep(5)







x = WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#styleguide-v2 > div.banner-container > a:nth-child(2)"))).click()`

Comment: No!
First `WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#styleguide-v2 > div.banner-container > a:nth-child(2)")))`
After that `time.sleep(5)` and only after that
`driver.findelement.....click()`

Comment: Unfortunately, it is giving the same error

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException:

Comment: Well, I really don't know.. Try using `element_to_be_clickable` condition instead the `visibility_of_element_located`.

Comment: Lol, that worked.

Thanks a lot for your time. It would actually be nice of you if you provided an explanation